# R: How to extract sets of multidimensional array values according to another matrix

Tags: r

Suppose I have a 4 dimensional n x n x n x n array A. A is a distance matrix, such that A[i,j,l,k] is the distance from location i,j to location pair l,k. Suppose I have an nxn matrix of location types T, lets say the types can be 0, 1, or 2, so T[i,j]=2 means the i,jth location is type 2. What is the easiest way to extract all the [i,j,l,k] entries of A such that T[i,j]=2 and T[l,k]=1, meaning the distances of all paths from a type 1 location to a type 2 location.

My thought was to use something like

```
type.0 = which(T == 0, arr.ind=T) 
type.1 = which(T == 1, arr.ind=T)
type.2 = which(T == 2, arr.ind=T)
```

But the problem is that because A is four dimensional, the way R does its indexing its not like you can just do A[type.0,type.1]. Of course I could do it with loops, but is there a better way of doing it.

I couldn't find a past answer on here, but its possible I missed something.

Here is a simple test case with two types 0 and 1, a 2x2 lattice of locations (1,1), type 0 (1,2), type 0, (2,1), type 1, and (2,2) type 1.

```
A = array(c(0,1,1,1.4,1,0,1.4,1,1,1.4,0,1,1.4,1,1,0), dim = c(2, 2, 2, 2))
T = matrix(c(0,1,0,1),2,2)
```

I want all the distances from a type 0 cell to a type 1 cell

Comment: Should be fairly simple. You've already tumbled to the `which( , arr.ind=TRUE)` trick.  Why not post a small test case that has an instances of A and T?

Comment: test case now posted above

Comment: yeah for simplicity I made the test problem only types 0 and 1, sorry

Comment: Please don't use `T` as a variable name in R. It is a reserved word standing for `True`.

Comment: oh good point, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that there is a more elegant way of doing this. Its inspired by DWin's solution but takes care of all potential combinations of getting from a type 0 to a type 1 cell. Let me know if you guys think of a better way

```
> type
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0



type.0 = which(type == 0, arr.ind=T) #locations of type 0 cells
type.1 = which(type == 1, arr.ind=T) #locations of type 1 cells

nlocs0 = length(type.0[,1]) #number of locations of type 0
nlocs1 = length(type.1[,1]) #number of locations of type 1

reploc0 = rbind( do.call(rbind, rep(list(type.0), nlocs1)) ) #rbinded on top of itself nloc1 times
reploc1 = rbind( do.call(rbind, rep(list(type.1[1,]), nlocs0)) ) #rbinding the first location of type.1 on top of itself nlocs0 times


if(nlocs1>1){
  for(i in 2:nlocs1){
    reploc1 = rbind( rbind( do.call(rbind, rep(list(type.1[i,]), nlocs0)) ), reploc1)
  } 
}

d0_1 = A[cbind(reploc0,reploc1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have changed the request from the one stated in the first paragraph. See if this answers the second version.

```
 A [ cbind( which(T == 0, arr.ind=TRUE), which(T == 1, arr.ind=TRUE) )]
#[1] 1 1
```

(At first I thought you might need abind but cbind works fine.)

Comment: actually this is not quite right I think it gives the distances of some of the paths but not all of them. There are 4 ways to get from type 0 to type 1. (1,1)->(2,1), (1,1)->(2,2), (1,2)->(2,1), or (1,2)->(2,2), but I think if you look at the size of which(T == 0, arr.ind=TRUE) and size of which(T == 1, arr.ind=TRUE) you can rbind appropriately to get the complete answer.